# CUMSUM along rows in segments - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, segments, cumsum

I have data in array `A = 100 X 612`.  I need to add cumulatively in `12` column segments `51` times and store the result in a new array `B = 100 X 612`.  Final array `B` is summed cumulatively along `12` columns then continuing again using `cumsum` along columns `13:24` and continuing like this until the end columns `601:612`.  This is repeated `100` times in row sequence.

I've tried this using loops multiple times but can't get the answer - there must be a simpler way to get the solution..too dependent on loops!

```
inx = 1:12:612; %use and index   
for i = 1:100;
    for j = 1:612;
        for k = 1:51;
            B(i,j) = cumsum(A(i,inx(k):inx(k)+11));
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lightweight [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and the necessary [`cumsum`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) -

```
intv = 12 %// interval or segment length
B = reshape(cumsum(reshape(A,size(A,1),intv,[]),2),size(A))
```

Basic idea here to reshape input array into a 3D array keeping the number of rows the same and with each row ending at `intv` lengths. Then, performing `cumsum` along rows and finally reshaping back to the size of input array.

Comment: @user2100039 Edited with comments on it, hope those make sense.